# Buffering ends after 1min while playback rtsp-stream

Tags: android, video-streaming, rtsp

I have written a small app, that just displays videodata from rtsp-stream (using MediaPlayer-class and SurfaceView-class). Rtsp-stream is created with vlc 2.0.0.

It works fine, but after 1min playback ends.

In logcat I've found the following lines:

// ...

E/Overlay (  138): Overlay is not ready to queue buffers

I/MyHandler(  138): received BYE on track index 0

E/OMX-VDEC-720P(  138):  Rxd i/p EOS, Notify Driver that EOS has been reached

E/OMX-VDEC-720P(  138):  Output EOS has been reached

E/OMX-VDEC-720P(  138):  Rxd OMX_COMPONENT_GENERATE_EOS_DONE

D/XXX     (10485): onCompletion() called

// ...

Seems that (decoder?) buffers are full and so the playback comes to an end.
Can I handle these buffers, so that new data can be received?

This time I solved that by waiting for onCompletion-Event to reset/restart
MediaPlayer, but that's not really the way to do this, right?

Does anyone have a solution/idea for this?

Greetzn + thanx in advance ...

Answer (score 1):

Probably the session timeout is being reached. You can check the headers sent back in the `PLAY` request to see if there is a `timeout=` directive given to you!

If there is you have to make a `GET_PARAMETER` request every so many seconds as indicated by the value of that header otherwise the server will kill your session.

Also see [Is there such a RTSP Ping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502856/is-there-such-a-rtsp-ping/11503206#11503206)

If you need anything else let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet. Did you try placing it on an asyncTask? or upon completion of your buffering it plays out?.

What you can also do is on AsyncTask, you may change the OnProgressUpdate() which then can either play when you have reached a certain buffer or play completely when it is complete.

Comment: Initiation of MediaPlayer / SurfaceView is made in mainthread. For preparation mediadata (filling buffers) I use MediaPlayer.prepareAsync(), which runs in its own thread. What do you mean, should I run in AsyncTask-environment? (By the way: the stream is not progressive. It's data from a webcam...)

Comment: Okay... Sorry I didn't know it was as you go. I thought it was video in the phone.